# How can I distort images like Imagemagick's shepard's distortion in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, imagemagick

### The problem

I know node isn't meant for cpu intensive processing, but I'm kind of stuck with node for this problem. I want to distort an image like Imagemagick's shepard's distortion:

[image: original]
[image: distorted]

Basically a grid warp, or liquify kind of effect. How can I distort an image in this manner in node? Note, I'm running node on a server that doesn't have the ability to install Imagemagick, so I can't use an exec or spawn to run Imagemagick indirectly.

See also: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards

### What I've tried so far

I've looked for a library that implements this kind of distortion on npm, but haven't been able to find any. There are plenty of libraries that do things like resizing, cropping, perspective warping, etc. But none that handle distortion of this kind.

Furthermore, I've looked at client side libraries that use canvas to implement this transformation, but also haven't been able to find anything there. As for third party services, cloudinary (the image processing service) implements a ton of image manipulations, but unfortunately nothing like this. The closest thing they have is a four-point perspective warp.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far, and what the specific part of the problem are you struggling with. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @scagood No problem, added a bit of background

Answer (score 1):

> you can use graphicsMagick module `gm` and configure it to use
>   `imageMagick`

**Module Installation** : `npm install gm`

> Configure it to use `imageMagick` by

`const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true})`

Find the link to the module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm).

Comment: > Note, I'm running node on a server that doesn't have the ability to install imagemagick, so I can't use a exec or spawn to run imagemagick indirectly.

Comment: you don't need to run imagemagick, imagemagick just needs to be installed in the server.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It isn't